# Opening Forwarded emails from Mac Users

Tags: windows, macos, email, file-format

I am running Outlook 2007.  Whenever a mac user forwards me an email, it has a MIME type, "x-apple-msg-attachment" .  What program can I use to view such messages? Outlook won't open them.

Comment: Does it have an extension?

Comment: Tell the user to not be an idiot and forward emails the normal way, inlined, and *not* as attachment. The regular *Forward* menu item is just above *Forward as Attachment* in the *Message* menu.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `.eml` extension? In my limited testing, this is the file format when selecting to forward as attachment. It's just the raw message source.

Comment: Adding the .eml extension allows outlook to open the file, but it ends up being garbage.